# Displaying elapsed time in an html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, timer

Im trying to display an elapsed time on an html page by which i need a 48 hour timer which counts down hh:mm:ss down to 0, which will start counting down when start is pressed and just run down to 0 some example code or any help would be grate.

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp, for instance.

Comment: Are you asking about Java or Javascript?

Comment: Im asking for advise for the most simplistic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend making use of an existing countdown plugin, these are readily available written in jQuery (The popular JavaScript library).

Here's one that I just plucked from the web:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/

You will be able to make a minor modification to how you start the timer within the page (IE: by attaching it to a button click event).